# java/jackson - resolve during parsing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a group which contains a list of persons:

```
class Person {
    ...
}

class Group {
    public Person findPerson(String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Say I have an input JSON (representation of `SomeDataClass` - see below) which refer to a person by its name:

```
{
    ...
    "person" : "Bill"
}
```

I am using Jackson to parse this input JSON. By default, Jackson parses this the `person` field to a `String`. Is it possible to change this, such that the person is resolved/looked up during parsing?

```
class SomeDataClass {
    ...

    @JsonProperty("person")
    protected Person person;
}
```

Note that I do not want to create a new person. I want to look it up, by calling  the function `getPerson` on an instance of `Group`. This means that I must have access to the group during the parsing. There are several groups at runtime, so it is not singleton.

**update**

I am aware of the `@JsonDeserialize(using = XYZ.cass)` possibility, but this does not allow me to pass the group to the custom deserializer. As said, there are multiple groups, so it is not singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with Jackson. You could try to store your reference to the group in a `ThreadLocal`, so your deserializer is using the correct group.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does have support for Object Ids, via `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation. But it is assumed that references using ids ("Bill" in this case) may be resolved by matching definitions within JSON content, so this may not work for your case.

You may need to handle resolution yourself; if you define `setPerson(String)`, method itself could try locating actual instance to use. But that does require use of `ThreadLocal`, as mentioned.
Another alternative could be custom deserializer, which would use "attribute"s via `DeserializationContext`; but you still need to provide such mappings so it does not help a lot.